# Arduino BLE Project (esp32)

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, project, iot, esp32

I want to make a device project that perform to receive data(device id) continuously from another four BLE(esp32 module). Can I do this by using one Arduino with one esp32 module? or needs 4 module to receive data from 4 individual device? There will also have 4 led for 4 device, if any device go out of range corresponding led turn off and if get signal led turn on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A BLE device can have multiple connections, so one should be fine.